# Cannot resolve .local hostname after upgrading to macOS Sierra

Tags: localhost, hostname, macos-sierra

I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra and i cannot resolve my .local hostnames anymore.

I've tried restoring the httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files, but it didn't help.

I can however reach my webserver using the IP address, but not with the .local hostname. If i ping the IP, it works perfectly, but pinging the hostname gives "Unknown host". Running "host mymac.local" gives Host server.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN).

I also tried setting the ComputerName, HostName and LocalHostName with the scutil.

Obviously reboot didn't help either.

Anyone experiencing the same issue or have any idea how this could be resolved? Thanks a lot, very appreciated!

Comment: Def not off-topic in my case, when the "tools used primarily for programming" are a Mac to build an iOS Meteor Cordova app that's being debugged with Xcode and I want my build system to mirror a real production build by not using "localhost", and I don't want to have to change an explicit IP in the phone app's settings if the Mac's IP changes.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that works for me on Mac OS Sierra.

- Open System preferences
- Open Sharing
- Click 'edit...' computer name
- Check 'Use dynamic global hostname'
- Check 'Advertise services in domain using Bonjour'
- Turn on 'file sharing'

[image: Please see the attached image]

Comment: THIS WORKS! Not sure what it triggers but it seems to refresh the local dns

Comment: didn't work for me, do I need to restart Mac ?

Comment: I had to enter a hostname, otherwise it wouldn't save the changes.

Answer (score 5):

Open system preferences and in Sharing enable one of the services.

I'm not sure why this works but I'm assuming it has to do with Bonjour name resolving that's only enabled if at least one of the services are started.

Alternatively add it to your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem. Turning on the one of the sharing services has fixed it. @sigget your solution rocks!!

Comment: didn't work for me, do I need to restart Mac ?

Comment: Yes! This still works to solve it in 2019 in Mojave.